# Salesforce1 Compact layout for Tasks

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have added couple of fields to the Task object. The custom fields are exposed on the Task Page Layout.

To display the same custom fields on Salesforce1, I created a new Tasks Compact Layout and added the new custom fields.

But, the layout in Salesforce1 is not displaying the new custom fields when I try creating a new task from publisher action.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Yeah. The primary compact layout is for the list views. For the edit view, we have to modify the layout on the "New Action" event for the object. I just found it.

Answer (score 2):

Compact layouts control what appears in a record's highlights area (that dark area at the top of most records in Salesforce1), in mobile cards for enhanced lookups, and in the list of fields that are displayed in the Chatter feed item when creating a record through a publisher action. The rest of the record home in Salesforce1 uses the fields in the page layout, not the compact layout.

List views are controlled by the actual columns in the list views, not the compact layout. However, for tasks the compact layout also controls what appears in the Tasks tab of Salesforce1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When we add the New Action for the object, we can define the layout for that particular action.